# How do you stub a file.read that happens inside a File.open block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do I stub a file.read call so that it returns what I want it to? The following does not work:

```
def write_something
  File.open('file.txt') do |f|
    return contents = f.read
  end
end
# rspec
describe 'stub .read' do
  it 'should work' do
    File.stub(:read) { 'stubbed read' }
    write_something.should == 'stubbed read'
  end
end
```

It looks like the stub is being applied to the `File` class and not the file instance inside my block. So `File.read` returns `stubbed read` as expected. But when I run my spec it fails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I should note that `File.open` is just one part of Ruby’s very large I/O API, and so your test is likely to be very strongly coupled to your implementation, and unlikely to survive much refactoring. Further, one must be careful with “global” mocking (i.e. of a constant or all instances) as it can unintentionally mock usages elsewhere, causing confusing errors and failures.

**Instead of mocking, consider either creating an actual file on disk (using [`Tempfile`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html)) or using a broader I/O mocking library (e.g. [FakeFS](https://rubygems.org/gems/fakefs)).**

If you still wish to use mocking you can somewhat safely stub `File.open` to yield a double (and only when called with the correct argument):

```
file = instance_double(File, read: 'stubbed read')
allow(File).to receive(:open).and_call_original
allow(File).to receive(:open).with('file.txt') { |&block| block.call(file) }
```

or, somewhat dangerously, stub all instances:

```
allow_any_instance_of(File).to receive(:read).and_return('stubbed read')
```

Comment: `any_instance` works but using the double gives me `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`. Any idea how to get it to work with the `double`?

Comment: @Brand Sorry, this actually took a while to figure out what was happening as I initially (and wrongly) thought RSpec was to blame. You can't implicitly call a block from within another block, so you have to explicitly accept and call the block in the stubbed implementation. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

The main point is to make `File.open` to return an object that will respond to `read` with the content you want, here's the code:

```
    it "how to mock ruby File.open with rspec 3.4" do
      filename = 'somefile.txt'
      content = "this would be the content of the file"
      # this is how to mock File.open:
      allow(File).to receive(:open).with(filename, 'r').and_yield( StringIO.new(content) )
      # you can have more then one of this allow

      # simple test to see that StringIO responds to read()
      expect(StringIO.new(content).read).to eq(content)

      result = ""
      File.open('somefile.txt', 'r') { |f| result = f.read }
      expect(result).to eq(content)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it

```
    describe 'write_something' do
      it 'should work' do  
        file_double = instance_double('File')
        expect(File).to receive(:open).with('file.txt').and_yield(file_double)
        expect(file_double).to receive(:read).and_return('file content')
        content = write_something
        expect(content).to eq('file content')
      end
    end
```